# javascript array to sort null first then descend order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm struggle to get array to sort the order but need to put null on top first then descend order for eg

```
var test = ["1998", "2005", null, "2015", "2022"];
```

I would like expect it to order in `[null, "2022", "2015", "2005", "1998"]`;

What I've tried.

```
test.sort(function(a, b) {
  return (
    (b === null) - (a === null) ||
    ("" + b).localeCompare(a)
  );
});
```

the problem is I'm using typescript, as there was error:

The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type `any`, `number`, `bigInt` or an `enum` type.

The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type `any`, `number`, `bigInt` or an `enum` type.

How do I resolve the issue?

Comment: `+(b === null) - +(a === null)`

Comment: FYI: You need to use `a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { numeric: true }))` or `+a - +b` if you are sorting numbers in string format. Just localeCompare woudn't work if you have a 
a `"200"` in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of subtracting booleans, you can explicitly write out the conditions.

```js
let test = ["1998", "2005", null, "2015", null, null, "2022", null];
test.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a === b) return 0;
  if (a === null) return -1;
  if (b === null) return 1;
  return b.localeCompare(a);
});
console.log(test);
```

Alternatively, you can use the unary plus operator to coerce to a number.

```js
let test = ["1998", "2005", null, "2015", null, null, "2022", null];
test.sort((a, b) => +(b === null) - +(a === null) || ("" + b).localeCompare("" + a));
console.log(test);
```

Comment: `+(...) - +(...)` really? minus takes the operands as number

Comment: @NinaScholz TypeScript will complain without adding `+` to both operands. "The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type."

Comment: didn't know. ts is not my language.

Comment: This has solved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort()` then follow by `reverse()` as follow

```js
var test = ["1998", "2005", null, "2015", "2022"];

console.log(test.sort().reverse())
```

which produces

```
[ null, '2022', '2015', '2005', '1998' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

### The TypeScript error

The reason you get these errors is your attempt to subtract `boolean` by `boolean` which is invalid:

```
const result = true - true
//             ^^^^^^^^^^^
//             The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of
//             type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.ts(2363)
```

You must convert `boolean` to apply the operation. i.e. turn it into one of `any`, `number`, `bigInt`, or `enum`.

### Sort

In this case, a `boolean` is converted to `0 | 1` by JavaScript. So, do it explicitly in TypeScript.

```
test.sort(function(a, b) {
  return (
    +(b === null) - +(a === null) ||
    ("" + b).localeCompare(a)
  );
});
```

After this, you may still see an error:

```
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2769)
```

This is because the variable `a` has a type `string | null` but `localeCompare` need a `string`. In another word, `("" + b).localeCompare(a)` only make scene if both `a` and `b` are of type `string`(in TypeScript). So just separate the `null` check:

```
test.sort(function (a, b) {
  if (a === null) return -1 // [a, b]
  if (b === null) return 1  // [b, a]
  return b.localeCompare(a)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sort `null` to top and the rest by value.

```js
const
    test = ["1998", "2005", null, "2015", "2022"];

test.sort((a, b) => (b === null) - (a === null) || b - a);

console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localeCompare` and with ternary operator for shorter syntax

```js
const test = ["1998", "2005", null, "2015", "2022"];

test.sort((a, b) => a === null ? -1 : b === null ? 1 : b.localeCompare(a));

console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

This Has solved the problem. Thank you. By the way you can change null to "" if there is blank space just in case.

```js
let test = ["1998", "2005", "", "2015", "", "", "2022", ""];
test.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a === b) return 0;
  if (a === "") return -1;
  if (b === "") return 1;
  return b.localeCompare(a);
});
console.log(test);
```

```js
let test = ["1998", "2005", "", "2015", "", "", "2022", ""];
test.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a === b) return 0;
  if (a === "") return -1;
  if (b === "") return 1;
  return b.localeCompare(a);
});
console.log(test);
```